# Editar formato de Excel desde Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

Hola otra vez a todos!

Se que últimamente estoy un poco intenso con las preguntas, pero os dejo otra, ya que vuestra ayuda me está sacando de muchos atolladeros.

Me gustaría predefinirle un filtro, definir un tamaño de la celda, color y demás a una hoja de Excel desde Python, es decir, que cuando se genere el Excel final, este tenga el formato de Excel que yo quiera. ¿Eso es posible con pandas u openpyxl?

Un saludo y muchas gracias de antemano!

Dejo aquí el código que estoy usando de ejemplo:

```
from tkinter import *
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd

path='C:/Users/jose.velazquez/Desktop/Reporte.xlsx'

difproyectos=[]
libro = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)

hoja = libro['Datos']
hoja2 = libro['Config']
prueba_excel=pd.read_excel(path,sheet_name="Datos")
prueba_excel2=pd.read_excel(path,sheet_name="Config")
row_count = hoja.max_row
column_count = hoja.max_column
tarea_row = hoja2.max_row

for i in range (tarea_row-1):
     difproyectos.append(prueba_excel2.at[i,'Proyectos'])

prueba_excel['A1'].font = Font(color='white',bold=True)

grabar=pd.ExcelWriter(path)
prueba_excel.to_excel(grabar,index=False,sheet_name="Datos")
prueba_excel2.to_excel(grabar,index=False,sheet_name="Config")
grabar.save()
```

Comment: Buen día, respuesta corta, si es posible crear formato, agregar tablas, gráficas, tamaños y colores de celdas etcétera. Para darte una respuesta más precisa necesitarías agregar a tu pregunta exactamente lo que quieres hacer, lo que has intentado y lo que no funciona.

Comment: Buenos días y gracias por la respuesta! Me gustaría, dado el código de arriba, cambiar el color de letra y porner en negrita la primera fila, la de titulo, ponerle un color de fondo y agregarle un título, cargando previamente un excel. Ahí he colocado un comando, el de font, que no me ha funcionado. ¿Sirve eso, o necesitarías más datos? Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Como no agregaste los datos de tus `dataframes`, cree un ejemplo básico para generar un archivo de Excel donde se crea una celda combinada con formato, el `dataframe` de prueba y una celda con formato.

Toda la documentación de como dar formato a las celdas, crear tablas, gráficas, etcétera, está [aquí](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/index.html)

```
import pandas as pd

# Dataframe de prueba
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2], 'B':[3,4]})

# Creamos el archivo
with pd.ExcelWriter('Prueba.xlsx', engine="xlsxwriter") as writer:
    workbook = writer.book
    
    #Formato para una celda
    idx_format = workbook.add_format({
        'bold': True,
        'border': 0,
        'font_color': '#F79646'})
    
    #Formato para celdas combinadas
    merge_format = workbook.add_format({
        'bold': True,
        'align': 'center',
        'valign': 'center',
        'border': 0,
        'font_color': 'white',
        'bg_color': '#F79646'})
    
    #Agregamos el dataframe a la hoja "Prueba"
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Prueba', startrow=1, startcol=0)
    
    #Seleccionamos la hoja "Prueba"
    ws = writer.sheets['Prueba']
    
    #Creamos una celda combinada y escribimos con el formato de celda combinada
    ws.merge_range(0, 0, 0, 2, 'Esto es una prueba', merge_format)
    
    #Escribimos en una celda con el formato de celda
    ws.write(5 , 0, 'Celda', idx_format)
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias de verdad!! Con este ejemplo tengo suficiente como para adaptar el mío. Sabes como añadir los filtros? (perdón por abusar un poquito)

Comment: Está en la documentación que te mandé, vienen ejemplos de como hacer varias cosas, ¿La revisaste? Recuerda que parte de la cultura de Stack Overflow es mostrar un esfuerzo por resolver tus dudas

Comment: Buenas de nuevo! Lo vi después de preguntar, fui demasiado rápido, ya se como utilizarlo y lo tengo dentro de mi código. Muchas gracias de nuevo!

Comment: ¡No hay de qué! Saludos